# Solr fuzzy search on 'hotdog' and 'hot dog'

Tags: solr, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

New to Solr search, I can't make it to happen so that when I search `Hot dog`, it can find `hotdog`, and when I search `hotdog`, it can find `hot dog`.
Did try to put it into synonyms.txt, but does not work.
Did try `text_general`, `text_en`, and `text_en_splitting`.

Did try hotdog~, "hot dog"~14, "hot~ dog~"~14

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by adding the following line into the synonyms.txt file.

> hot dog, hotdog

Make sure that you set **expand=true** in the SynonymFilterFactory definition.

It will be better to use SynonymFilterFactory during index time.Then re-index your data and it should work.

Btw, I am using the Solr 3.6.1 version and used text_general for indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `hot~ AND dog~` assuming that the default field is set to the field you are searching.

If you want to do a explicit search using field name the query will be like below.

```
fieldName:hot~ AND fieldName:dog~
```